OpenApi Generator and string versus DateTime
I am using OpenApi Generator (v7.4.0) to create client classes through https://api.myptv.com/meta/services/account/v1/openapi.json
One of the offered methods offers optional parameters which are seen as "type:string with a format:date" (in the machine readable spec)
{
   "name": "startDate",
   "in": "query",
   "description": "The date from when on the usage is requested formatted according 

to RFC 3339.\nIf only the startDate is given,
the response contains the usage only for this date.",
"schema": {
"type": "string",
"format": "date",
"example": "2024-03-26"
}
}
Wrapped into public UsageResponse GetUsage(DateTime? startDate = default(DateTime?), DateTime? endDate = default(DateTime?), int operationIndex = 0)
By calling the method from C# with a DateTime value I get
{
  "description": "The validation of the request failed. Details can be found in 'causes'.",
  "errorCode": "GENERAL_VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "traceId": "xxx",
  "causes": [
    {
      "description": "A parameter is set to an invalid value.",
      "errorCode": "GENERAL_INVALID_VALUE",
      "parameter": "startDate",
      "details": {
        "value": "2024-04-23T00:00:00.0000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "A parameter is set to an invalid value.",
      "errorCode": "GENERAL_INVALID_VALUE",
      "parameter": "endDate",
      "details": {
        "value": "2024-05-22T00:00:00.0000000"
      }
    }
  ]
}

How to get rid of that type mismatch?
